# Perl Split File Into Lines and Variables

Tags: perl, parsing

I am currently splitting a Perl file which holds some user/password information and am doing it successfully, but am not satisfied with my code. I am sure there is a better way to do it in Perl (I am a beginner). If someone could come up with a slicker way that would be great!

```
my $i = 1;
my $DB;
my $DBHOST;
my $DBUSER;
my $DBPASS;    
my $filename = "some_file";
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    if ($i == 1) {
        $DB = (split /=/, $row)[1];
    }
    if ($i == 2) {
        $DBHOST = (split /=/, $row)[1];
    }
    if ($i == 3) {
        $DBUSER = (split /=/, $row)[1];
    }
    if ($i == 4) {  
        $DBPASS = (split /=/, $row)[1];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask for code review

Comment: Read about strict, warnings, closure of filehandles and $i++ could be replaced with $. in your case.

Comment: What database are you using? The *best* way to do this is to let the database server parse the credentials file directly. For example, MySQL has [option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) and Postgres has [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[map()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) is pretty handy for things like this:

```
my ($DB, $DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS) = map {$_ =~ /.*?=(.*)/} <$fh>;
```

What's happening:

- `map()` operates on lists, so it treats `<$fh>` as one
- for each element in the list (a file line in this case), assign it into the default variable (`$_`)
- then, capture the part of the line we want using regex, return it, and assign it to the relevant variable on the left-hand-side (on each iteration of the file, each one of the receiving variables are shifted as well)
- the regex operates as follows:

  `/
      .*? # ignore everything, non greedy until we match a
      =   # our delimiter
      (   # begin capture
      .*  # capture everything until end of line (less the newline char)
      )   # end capture
  /`

Note that this solution will iterate all the way through the whole file, even after all four of the variables are populated (as does the way you've done it in your OP).

Also note that there's no error checking here, so if a value isn't captured, you'll get warnings related to undefined variables.

Comment: Wow thank you, can you explain what exactly is going on here? Documentation page isn't too helpful.

Comment: I can see that '.*?' matches any character, 0 or more times (except line terminators?), then match '=', then once again any character 0 or more times. Then map basically does this foreach of those variables? How does it get the value after the '=' and assign it to the variable?

Comment: @user2774695 that's what the regex capture does. It captures everything after the equal sign, and that's the value that's returned, and by default, Perl regex doesn't match newlines by default... the `/m` modifier can be used for that. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: That may as well be `map { /=(.*)/ } <$fh>`. The `.*?` doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Borodin: what if the password contains a `=`?

Comment: @stevieb: That will work. Try it. `=` on its own matches the first equals sign. Then `(.*)`captures the rest of the line.

Comment: @Borodin I have to admit I need to re-visit the re docs, as what you've stated indeed works. Thanks for pointing that out. I should have known that the last greedy grabber would ensure the longest-length match...

Comment: @stevieb: It's not to do with the last item being greedy; it's just that regex patterns are matched left to right, and reassessed (backtracked) only if later parts of the pattern cannot match that way. The `=` matches the first equals sign, and then "zero or more of anything" cannot fail, so it just matches and captures the rest of the string. There's a common misconception about greedy/non-greedy patterns that they somehow magically force the entire pattern to match in a way that maximises their length.

Comment: All they do in fact is choose between whether the element matches as much as possible and then shrinks if necessary until the rest of the pattern succeeds, or as little as possible and then grows until the rest of the pattern succeeds. So `.*?=` will try with `.*?` matching zero characters and check whether `=` can match. If not it will *backtrack* and try with it matching one character, then two, and so on until the `=` character can match. The result is that the `=` is matched by the first equals sign, which is the same as just an `=` on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do away with your individual variables and store the connection information in a hash.

```
my %db_conn;

while (<$fh>) {
  my ($key, $val) = split /=/, $_, 2;
  $db_conn{$key} = $val;
}
```

Of course, this assumes that whatever is to the left of the `=` on each line is a unique identifier for the value.